# Content not showing in TextFields when editing in SwiftUI Xcode 13 iOS15

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I recently updated Xcode from 12.5 (iOS14) to Xcode 13 (iOS15) and my projects no longer show content on `TextFields` when editing info in a form. For instance, let's pretend for a moment that the following code is used when editing info in a `Form` and you want to show the name `Jason` in the textField as soon as the views load so the user knows what he/she is editing. In Xcode 12.5 (iOS14) the following code would show the `Jason` as soon as the form appeared, in Xcode 13 (iOS15) it doesn't show the name until you tap on the textField.

Has anyone seen this? Is there a solution?

```
struct TestingTextFields: View {

    @State private var inputName:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form{
            TextField("Enter Name", text:$inputName)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.inputName = "Jason" // name doesn't show until user taps on the textField
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see behaviour, One solution could be to apply the `onAppear` modifier right on your `TextField`

Comment: You're right, adding the `onAppear` modifier directly to the fields makes the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine as-is with Xcode 13.0 (13A233)

Comment: For your info, your code as shown, does not work for me on macos 12.beta9, compiled using xcode-beta5 (13A5212g), target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Works for me on macos 12.beta9 only app. Tested on real devices iMac and iPhone with ios15.
 Works everywhere if you "attach" `onAppear`to the `TextField`.

Comment: @Asperi - Hmm, that's weird, I'm also using Xcode 13 (13A233), and doesn't work on the simulator nor the device. @ workingdog - thank you for the info.